# How to fetch EntityGraph dynamically in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am developing an application using Spring Boot using JPA.
In the application I am exposing a rest API. I do not want to use Spring data rest as I want to have full control of the data.

I am not able to figure out how to use EntityGraph dynamically.

Suppose I have following model taken from [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling)

```
   @Entity
class Product {

  @ManyToMany
  Set<Tag> tags;

  // other properties omitted
}

interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Customer, Long> {

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"tags"})
  Product findOneById(Long id);
}
```

I have following rest link to access Product
http://localhost:8090/product/1

It returns to me a product with id 1

Questions:

1. Will it by default fetch **tags** as we have mentioned @EntityGraph?
   If yes, then can this be configured on demand? Say, if in the query
   string I have **include=tags**, then only I want to fetch product with
   its tags.

I found [this](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-2-define/) article but not sure how this can be of help.

Comment: If you need dynamic EntityGraphs, you might be interested in this project: [spring-data-jpa-entity-graph](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The definition of the EntityGraph in the Spring Data JPA Repository is static. If you want to have it dynamic you need to do this programatically like in the page you linked to:

```
EntityGraph<Product> graph = this.em.createEntityGraph(Product.class);
graph.addAttributeNodes("tags"); //here you can add or not the tags

Map<String, Object> hints = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hints.put("javax.persistence.loadgraph", graph);

this.em.find(Product.class, orderId, hints);
```

Also you can define the method with the EntityGraph in your JPA Repository.

```
interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Product, Long> {

@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"tags"})
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id=:id")
Product findOneByIdWithEntityGraphTags(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

And then have a method in your service which uses this method with the EntityGraph or the built in `findOne(T id)` without the EntityGraph:

```
Product findOneById(Long id, boolean withTags){
  if(withTags){
    return productRepository.findOneByIdWithEntityGraphTags(id);
  } else {
    return productRepository.findOne(id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can choose EntityGraph at runtime, by using [Spring Data JPA EntityGraph](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph).
Setup quite simple:

- Add: `implementation 'com.cosium.spring.data:spring-data-jpa-entity-graph:2.0.7'` to build.gradle
- Add: `@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EntityGraphJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)` bellow `@SpringBootApplication`

Now, you can choose the best EntityGraph at runtime. Example (this is the example from [Spring Data JPA EntityGraph](https://github.com/Cosium/spring-data-jpa-entity-graph)):

```java
// This will apply 'Product.brand' named EntityGraph to findByLabel
productRepository.findByLabel("foo", EntityGraphs.named("Product.brand"));

// This will apply 'Product.supplier' named EntityGraph to findByLabel
productRepository.findByLabel("foo", EntityGraphs.named("Product.supplier"));

// This will apply 'supplier' attribute paths EntityGraph (don't need to define named EntityGraph) to findByLabel
productRepository.findByLabel("foo", EntityGraphUtils.fromAttributePaths("supplier"));
```

Please read the document for more information.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in the repository:

```
interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Product, Long> {

    Product findOneById(Long id);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"tags"})
    Product findOneWithTagsById(Long id);
}
```

and create a service method as Robert Niestroj proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an Entity graph as bellow, make sure the entity product class has a relation with the tag class.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {
        "tags"
    })
@Query( value = "select product from product)
List<Product> findAllProduct();
```