# Spring JPA data, multiple methods with same functionality

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa to interact with a database, however I've come across a problem: I can't define the same method multiple times with different named entities.

Consider:

```
class Repository {
    @EntityGraph(value = UserEo.FULL, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public Optional<UserEo> findUserEoByEmail/*Full*/(String email);

    @EntityGraph(value = UserEo.BRIEF, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public Optional<UserEo> findUserEoByEmail/*Brief*/(String email);
}
```

I'd like to have separate methods with different named graphs, but adding additional information to the name of the methods breaks spring. How can this be solved?

Comment: AFAIK you can name the part between find and By the way you want. Only exception to the rule would be the distinct key word. So findBriefUserEoByEmail and findFullUserEoByEmail should work i think.

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54876656/14225495. It looks like you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As comment suggests naming the methods correctly will not "break Spring". You can have:

```
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<UserEo, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(value = UserEo.FULL, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public Optional<UserEo> findFullByEmail(String email);
    @EntityGraph(value = UserEo.BRIEF, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public Optional<UserEo> findBriefByEmail(String email);
}
```

Or maybe you want to break stuff in two repositories, like:

```
public interface RepositoryFull extends JpaRepository<UserEo, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(value = UserEo.FULL, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public Optional<UserEo> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

and

```
public interface RepositoryBrief extends JpaRepository<UserEo, Long> {
    @EntityGraph(value = UserEo.BRIEF, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    public Optional<UserEo> findByEmail(String email);
}
```